# AWS Elastic IP and domain name association not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I've recently set up an AWS hosted zone and used Record set A (IPv4) to associate a static Elastic IP to my domain name but when I type my domain name in the browser it doesn't get resolved. I tried pinging the Elastic IP and got request time out. I've read every guideline on Amazon and they all indicate that you only need to create the Record set to use a domain. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first of the problem is that you're not able to ping your instance, please verify on the AWS Console that the instance shows the expected public IP address and that your Security Group is whitelisting the source of your ping.  If that is not working, show us the traceroute, also the question about the DNS resolution should probably be in a differente post.

Comment: Did you purchase your Domain Name from a registry? Is it registered on Route 53, or is it managed by an external Domain Name registry?

Comment: the domain has been transferred to Route 53

Answer (score 0):

In order to use [Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) as your DNS, point your domain to the AWS designated addresses. Registrars require the specification of usually at least two name servers.

Comment: my domain was transferred to route 53

Comment: Yes, but many times people inherit their old name servers when transferring a domain to Route 53. Make sure you domain's name servers are 4 name servers assigned to your Route 53 Hosted Zone. You can check your domain's name servers with a simple NS query: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/www.amazon.com